# FaviconsWebpackPlugin: outputting without injection?

Tags: webpack

I am outputting my HTML head document manually via templates. I have FaviconsWebpackPlugin installed and apparently working (the files are generated and correctly placed into the destination folder). However, I cannot apparently find the correct way to output them into my template.

```
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './x/head2.tpl',
            filename: '../y/head-site.tpl',
            hash: true,
            chunks : ['site'],
            inject: false,
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
            minify: false,
        }),
        ...
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
            logo: './z/favicon-src.png',
            inject: false,
        }),
       ...
```

Then in my template, I have things like:

```
  <% for (var css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
  <link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %>" rel="stylesheet">
  <% } %>
```

How can I output my favicons too?

I tried to debug this by placing `<% <pre><%= JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin, null, 2) %></pre>` into my template. If I set inject to true, then I get a bunch of headTags. If I set inject to false then I get nothing...

Is there a way to populate another array in `htmlWebpackPlugin.files`?

Comment: If you remain the inject as true in both of the plugins, do you see the fav icon meta tags injected?

Comment: Yes, setting inject to true will inject the images as well. 
The reason I am not injecting is that my HTML is loaded from Apache and processed via PHP, thile JS and CSS is received from Webpack. In production everything is OK. But when I run the dev server, then the injections always point to the static files. Therefore I am loading CSS like this:
<link href="<?=$loaderHost?>/lib/site.css?469e814befcb1a1e3596" rel="stylesheet">
and $loaderHost is set to be the webpack development server (eg: localhost:123456)

Comment: Probably there is a much better way to get it working. But it used to work in Webpack 3. Upgrading to Webpack 4 broke my setup. At the moment I just statically plop the HTML with the icons into my template (ugly). Or I may dynamically rewrite the HEAD when running in development and replace /lib/ references at runtime (even uglier)...

Comment: @Palantir there's an option for `favicon` in `html-webpack-plugin` which then will be available as `htmlWebpackPlugin.files.favicon`

Answer (score 0):

`html-webpack-plugin` has an option for `favicon` which then will be available in `htmlWebpackPlugin.files` object as `favicon` key.

Comment: This is not what I need. The option you mention allows to add a single file to your html. In my case it should get that info from the FaviconsWebpackPlugin, which generates a whole bunch of icons.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already know that [favicons-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin) uses [favicons](https://github.com/itgalaxy/favicons#usage) package internally to generate and icons.

You can directly use [favicons](https://github.com/itgalaxy/favicons#usage) package with [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) `templateParameters` options to add in `htmlWebpackPlugin.files`.

template/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
      <%= JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin, null, 2) %>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const favicons = require('favicons');

function toBase64(content) {
  return Buffer.from(content).toString('base64');
}

const source = './logo/favicon.svg';
favicon_prefix = '/url/path/';

const configuration = {
  appName: 'AppName',
  appDescription: '',
  version: '1.0.0',
  path: '/assets/',
  appShortName: null,
  developerName: null,
  developerURL: null,
  dir: 'auto',
  lang: 'en-US',
  background: '#fff',
  theme_color: '#fff',
  appleStatusBarStyle: 'black-translucent',
  display: 'standalone',
  orientation: 'any',
  start_url: '/?homescreen=1',
  logging: false,
  pixel_art: false,
  loadManifestWithCredentials: false,
  manifestRelativePaths: false,
  icons: {
    android: true,
    appleIcon: true,
    appleStartup: true,
    coast: true,
    favicons: true,
    firefox: true,
    windows: true,
    yandex: true
  }
}

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'AppName',
      template: 'template/index.html',
      templateParameters: async (compilation, assets, assetTags, options) => {
        const { html: tags, images, files } = await favicons(source, configuration);
        const _favicons = [...images, ...files].map(({ name, contents }) => ({
          name: favicon_prefix + name,
          contents: toBase64(contents) /* Remove toBase64 function if you want to check the contents. */
        }));
        assets['favicons'] = _favicons;
        return {
          compilation,
          webpackConfig: compilation.options,
          htmlWebpackPlugin: {
            tags: assetTags,
            files: assets,
            options
          },
        };
      }
    }),
  ]
};
```

**Note**: I have used [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) 5 with `html-webpack-plugin@5.0.0-alpha.10` and `favicon-webpack-plugin@5.0.0-alpha.3` because these libraries current stable version were not working with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) 5 at the moment.

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Chandan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "favicons-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-alpha.10",
    "safe-require": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```